# Build Perl from Source for Windows 10 using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, perl, cmake, nmake

I was reading this post.

http://www.cpan.org/src/README.html
and
http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.16.0/README.win32#Building

I extracted the files to:  `c:\Sources\perl-5.26.0\` Now I want to build it.

I set `CCTYPE       = MSVC141`

Now I run:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio 2017\Visual Studio Tools\VC\x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017
```

Later:

```
    C:\Sources\perl-5.26.0>win32\Makefile
    'win32\Makefile' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.

    C:\Sources\perl-5.26.0>nmake -f win32\Makefile

    Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.10.25019.0
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

    NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'config_H.vc'
    Stop.

    C:\Sources\perl-5.26.0>
```

With CMAKE:

```
mkdir c:\Sources\perl-5.26.0\bld
cd /d c:\Sources\perl-5.26.0\bld

cmake . -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="c:\Custom\perl" -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo  
CMake Error: The source directory "C:/Sources/perl-5.26.0/bld" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.

c:\Sources\perl-5.26.0\bld>
```

Sorry I forget to check the existence of: `CMakeLists.txt` file

**Is it possible to build perl instead of obtain downloading from** *ActivePerl (The installer is not working properly)* **or** *Strawberry-perl (the site was down)* **?**

Please tell me.

How I must define this variables:

```
MSVCDIR     = ???
CCHOME      = $(MSVCDIR)
CCINCDIR    = $(CCHOME)\include
CCLIBDIR    = $(CCHOME)\lib
```

My Output.

```
generate_uudmap.c
        link -out:..\generate_uudmap.exe @C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\nmFB0B.tmp
generate_uudmap.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_exit
generate_uudmap.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_fputc
generate_uudmap.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_fopen
generate_uudmap.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___acrt_iob_func
generate_uudmap.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_fclose
generate_uudmap.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___stdio_common_vfprintf
generate_uudmap.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__errno
generate_uudmap.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_fputs
generate_uudmap.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_strerror
msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _seh_filter_exe
msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _set_app_type
msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __setusermatherr
msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _configure_narrow_argv
msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _configure_narrow_argv
msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _initialize_narrow_environment
msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _initialize_narrow_environment
msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _get_initial_narrow_environment
msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _initterm
msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _initterm_e
msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol exit
msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _exit
msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _set_fmode
msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __p___argc
msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __p___argv
msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cexit
msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cexit
msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _c_exit
msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _register_thread_local_exe_atexit_callback
msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _configthreadlocale
msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _set_new_mode
msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __p__commode
msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __C_specific_handler
msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __C_specific_handler
msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _seh_filter_dll
msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _initialize_onexit_table
msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _register_onexit_function
msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _execute_onexit_table
msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _crt_atexit
msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _crt_at_quick_exit
msvcrt.lib(tncleanup.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_type_info_destroy_list
msvcrt.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol terminate
msvcrt.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
..\generate_uudmap.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 38 unresolved externals
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\bin\HostX64\x64\link.EXE"' : return code '0x460'
Stop.

c:\Sources\perl-5.26.0\win32>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`win32/Makefile` does not officially have support for building with Visual Studio 2017. But, it does have support for building with VS 2015. The reason building with Visual Studio 2015 tools require a separate configuration than with building with Visual Studio 2013 tools is the same for Visual Studio 2017 tools, so you can use the same configuration.

To do so:

- Open a "x64 Native Command Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017" command window from Start.
- Go to the directory in which you extracted the Perl 5.26.0 sources, and edit `win32/Makefile`:
- Set:

  ```
  CCTYPE      = MSVC140

  ...
  CCHOME      = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017
  CCINCDIR    = $(CCHOME)\include
  CCLIBDIR    = $(CCHOME)\lib\x64
  ```

  Noting the version dependent directory in `CCHOME`. Make sure you use the version that corresponds to what you have.
- Run `nmake` in `<perl source directory>\win32`. Now, I usually make some more changes, but this is the minimal amount of changes necessary to have a build.
- Then, `nmake test`, `nmake install`.

Note that `perl`s built with Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 may end up being rather useless because they link with the new platform runtime which OpenSSL does not work with. I think this means you are not going to be able to use modules such as `LWP`, `HTTP::Tiny` etc with `https`. I haven't investigated this a lot, so if I am wrong, I would love to be corrected.

Note that Visual Studio 2013 tools are also installed when you install Visual Studio 2017, so if you can live with certain [bugs](https://www.nu42.com/2016/06/msvc-printf-bug-affects-perl.html) and the fact that Perl's build config for VS 2013 by default ignores the C99 features included in VS 2013, or if you are willing to hand-edit config files, I have found building with that to be more reliable.

In general, you are better off using [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/). Using the MinGW toolchain saves a lot of time if you want to use modules that depend on C libraries.

Comment: One would have to be familiar with why earlier `perl`s would not build with Visual Studio 2015 to know that. I do wish `perl` source did not grab `stdio.h` data structures by the guts, but it does.